# Second dropdown values not showing after pageload

Tags: jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu, pageload

I have a second dropdown list which only shows the dropdown values AFTER I changed the value of the first dropdown. I would like to see the values in the second dropdown right after the page load though.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#parent_cat").change(function() {
        $(this).after('<div id="loader"></div>');
        $.get('../helper/loadsubcat.php?parent_cat=' + $(this).val(), function(data) {
            $("#sub_cat").html(data);
            $('#loader').slideUp(200, function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }); 
    });
});
</script>
```

Do you know, what I am missing here?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Jsfiddle? Increases your chances of an answer exponentially

Comment: Go to http://jsfiddle.net/ enter in your relevant HTML,CSS and Javascript so we can see a model and edit it. Although do be honest I don't know javascript too well and it's probably too late to except anymore answers.